# MATLAB program to convert the selected regions of 2D binary image to 3D image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to MATLAB, I am looking for a MATLAB code that can, generate the voxel coordinates of the selected regions in the 2D binary image (Please refer the link), and derive a 3D image from the voxel coordinates. Please help me. If there is any other methods I can do, then please guide me.

link for the image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B652zPkqD4IgeU0zaG5FYlN1NkE

Thankyou

Comment: There is no way (as I know) to derive a 3D image from a single 2D image without other information. Assuming that your example could represent a photo, you need at least a couple of photo (stereo images). In Matlab what you need (after some theory) maybe is the [Computer vision toolbox](https://it.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/index.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)